# How to read a 100x24 matrix from file and keep it in memory as a float matrix?

Tags: c++

Here is my code, i can save data in char matrix, but i want to save it in float matrix

```
const unsigned int HEIGHT = 100;
const unsigned int WIDTH = 24 ;



char arr[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

ifstream fin;
fin.open("PW.txt");
string line;

//let's assume here the proper size of input Map
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
{
    getline(fin, line);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
    {
        arr[i][j] = line[j];
    }
}

//let's assume here the proper size of input Map
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
    {
        cout << arr[i][j]  ;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show an excerpt from your file, so we can see what it looks like? And how did you save the file?

Comment: "i can save data in char matrix, but i want to save it in float matrix" - so what exactly is the problem? What *exactly* are you asking? What did you try? In what ways did it not work?

Comment: I don't understand your question : how do you expect to convert from char to float? As I understand your code the input file contains only lines of 24 char.

Comment: I saved a 100x24 matrix in a text file using Matlab. Now i want to read this data and save it in 2d matrix in visual studio c++. I want to read this matrix from the text file and save it in float type 2d matrix. In my code i can save it in char matrix, but i want to save it in float matrix

Comment: Each column is separated by '/t' and row by '/n'.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the internet for "c++ read file matrix" you may see code like this:

```
static const int MAX_ROWS = 100;
static const int MAX_COLUMNS = 24;

//...
double matrix[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLUMNS];
double value = 0.0;
for (int row = 0; row < MAX_ROWS; ++row)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < MAX_COLUMNS; ++column)
    {
        text_file >> value;
        matrix[row][column] = value;
    }
}
```

You can read a matrix of `float` by changing the data type from `double` to `float`.

Comment: Better to define the `text_file` variable before to make it more clear ;)